# Scipy integration returning negative values

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have some xdata and ydata. I have sorted my xdata and ydata such that ydata is increasing (ie highest y value at the end of the ydata array). ydata also contained some points = 0, and so I've also removed those points from xdata and ydata, leaving me with a purely positive, non-zero and increasing set of ydata (with corresponding xdata).

For some reason when I go val = scipy.integrate.simps(ydata,xdata) I get a negative value. I also get the exact same negative values when using cumtrapz. I then wrote my own cumtrapz function that simply sums 0.5*dx*(y[i]+y[i+1]) and get a nearly identical result, but positive. My question is why aren't the scipy functions correctly returning positive results? (Cannot share data publicly, however, I can describe the unsorted data as being an exponential decay, which I sort such that the largest y values are at the end of the ydata array).

Cheers any help appreciated

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post a [example]?

Comment: I said in the post that I'm not able to post the data....

Comment: You could maybe normalize your data or somehow reproduce that behavior so that the community can help you better.

Comment: It is `xdata` that should be increasing.  The integral will have the wrong sign if the `x` coordinates decrease.